# Connection reset by peer on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, nokogiri, open-uri

I'm writing a tiny parser that extract key information from interested site. I achieve this through `open-uri` and `nokogiri`

```
#inside controller
def some_method
    ...
    html = open(base_url)
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html.read)
    ...
end
```

When I run my application on local machine (any environment: dev or prod), all works fine. But when I deploy it to heroku, it stops working. I get this error every time

> Connection reset by peer

and I can't figure out why. I don't know why it works locally but not on heroku. It can't be because of high frequency of requests because I manually wait for few seconds. And seems that problem in not with target site - because heroku behaves similarly for other sites.

Answer (score 0):

Are you making the requests in response to a page request? You know about the 30 second request timeout, right?

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout

You could move it into a worker instead if that's the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but response comes to me up to 5-10 seconds (i see in dev console that request failed).

Comment: How are you executing the code? Page request, or through "heroku run rails c" or something like that?